# windows phone - iterating through .resx

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, resx

I am in the process of learning how to write apps for Windows Phone 7/8. I am working on a simple cookbook application. At first, I hard-coded all the values, but I then moved the data to .resx in order to localize the recipes. Now, what if I wanted to implement a search function? I don't think iterating through .resx is the desired approach. Can I use some sort of a database? Can I still localize that database?

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that you're talking about localizing an application. If that's the case, start with the [official guidelines on building a localized application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28VS.92%29.aspx).

You might also be interested in: [Localization Best Practices for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967552%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).